# How to draw a simple angle, two intersecting lines Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-styles

I'm trying to get an angle between the negative $y$-axis and the line passing through the origin. How is this done? I've looked at other forums, and the code seems quite complicated; is there not a simple way of doing this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [->,thick] (-3.5,0)--(3.5,0);
\node at (3.7,0) {\large{$x$}};
\draw [->,thick] (0,2)--(0,-3.5);
\draw[thick] (-3,-2)--(3,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can load the libraries `angles, quotes` and then use the `pic` option. I have applied some modifications to your code, for example, the axis lines are now equally long, and the label for the X axis is added together with the `\draw` command.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (O) at (0,0);

\draw [->,thick] (-3.5,0)--(3.5,0) node[right, at end] {\large$x$};
\draw [->,thick] (0,3.5) coordinate (topy) --(0,-3.5) coordinate (bottomy);
\draw[thick] (-3,-2) coordinate (line2) -- (3,2);

\path 
    (line2)
    -- (O)
    -- (bottomy)
  pic["$\alpha$",draw=red,<->,angle eccentricity=1.2,angle radius=1cm] {angle=line2--O--bottomy};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```